# How do I configure child routes of a child route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So I have some routes which are a children of a child route. You can see below that I have the app.routes root, then the async.routes ('httprx'), which are a child of app.routes and then spotify.routes which are a child of the async.routes.

It works ok if I'm nested one level deep i.e.

```
localhost:4000/#/httprx/http-examples
```

That loads the httpExamples component into the async.component's router-outlet. All good. The issue is if I navigate to

```
localhost:4000/#/httprx/spotify/search
```

It loads the spotify component into the the app.components router-outlet, replacing the async.component. I'm not sure why it's doing this. I guess it's something to do with the spotify.routes.

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'forms', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'forms', loadChildren: 'src/app/forms/forms.module#FormExamplesModule'},
  {path: 'httprx', loadChildren: 'src/app/http-rxjs/async.module.ts#HttpRxJsModule'},
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**async.routes.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'httprx',
    component: MainHttpRxJs,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'http-examples',  pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'http-examples', component: HttpExamples},
      {path: 'spotify', component: SpotifyDemoApp}
    ]
  },
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**async.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="http-examples" routerLinkActive="active">Http/RxJs Searches</a>
        <a routerLink="spotify" routerLinkActive="active">Spotify</a>
      </nav>
      <div id="container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
`
})
```

**spotify.routes.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'httprx/spotify',
    component: SpotifyDemoApp,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'search',  pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent }
    ]
  },
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**spotify.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: `
     <div class="spotify-component">
         <h4>Spotify</h4>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
```

Comment: I think you need `path: ''` in both of your child routes. Child routes does not have to be worried of what's before them.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work at all. That's the way the routing it setup on the "tour-of-heros" example in the docs but for some reason when I do the same it throws "ReferenceError: System is not defined" The only way I could get it to work was by specifying a matching path the to the parent route.

Comment: Are you sure that your path is supposed to be like : `'src/app/forms/forms.module#FormExamplesModule'` when using SystemJs ?! If this is just an example app I'd recommend you to use angular-cli (with webpack). This should work. (I might be missing something here + I'm not used to SystemJs).

Comment: That's not SystemJS. That's how to lazy load components using angular router.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues - basically Grandchild routes (in their own feature modules with their own routes). Did you ever figure it out?